# Updating Data Warehouse via ADO.NET Connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssis

I have built an SSIS package that looks at a source table and pushes this data to a data warehouse in Azure. So far it adds entries that are not in the warehouse but are in the source table. I'm confused as to how to do the update section of this package, where the data warehouse contains the same entry as the source table but needs to be updated to reflect changes made to the source table.

With OLE DB Connections there is a 'SQL' parameter in the 'custom options' section of the destinations advanced editor. There is no such ability with the ado.net destination advanced editor. What is the proper way to go about updating these entries?

Here is a screenshot of my package so far:
[image]

I've searched extensively and cannot find a clear answer to this. Please forgive the error on my part if this is a simple solution.

Comment: You'll find an ELT approach far more efficient, like 10X faster efficient. ELT = Extract from source, load directly to staging tables then Transform with T-SQL. If you just load those two sources to staging tables you can replace the rest with T-SQL. If you start to get to big data volumes, that approach just doesn't cut it. Sorts and OLEDB Command just do not scale for large datasets... well they do they just take forever (needlessly)

Comment: I'll restructure my plan and give this a try, 10x efficiency sounds excellent. My data sets aren't large yet but they are getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible approaches - Update with OLEDB Command and Update wwith intermediate table.

OLEDB Command Transformation runs specified command for each line of data block in data transformation. You simply add OLEDB Command to your data transformation, pick up *OLEDB Connection Manager* and enter parametric SQL command like this
[image]
Hitting ellipsis opens SQL Command Editor window
[image]
Having set SQL command with parameters, you can bind fields from data stream to parameters on the next tab
[image]
And this is it! More info - [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/ole-db-command-transformation).
Advantage of this method - it is simple. Disadvantage - for every update row a separate SQL command is fired, which is not good for performance.

Then you have an alternative with Update through intermediate table. Main idea - you store all table rows to be updated in a special table. Then - run SQL Command with SQL Update like

```
Update [tgt_tbl] Set [tgt_tbl].[field1] = [interm_tbl].[field1] 
    From [tgt_tbl] tgt  
    Inner Join [interm_tbl] itbl On tgt.key = itbl.key
```

This approach is more complex, but performance is definitely better.

Comment: This would be a good approach but I cannot use OLE DB as its not fully supported by azure data warehouse.

Comment: I was actually wrong, the second method you suggest is what I'll end up using it looks like. Thanks!